# SSO with keycloak

Tags: keycloak

We are considering to use the [keycloak](http://keycloak.jboss.org/) as our SSO framework.

1. According to the keycloak documentation for multi-tenancy support the application server should hold all the keycloak.json authentication files, the way to acquire those files is from the keycloak admin, is there a way to get them dynamically via API ? or at least to get the realm public key ? we would like to avoid to manually add this file for each realm to the application server (to avoid downtime, etc).
2. Another multi-tenancy related question - according to the documentation the same clients should be created for each realm, so if I have 100 realms and 10 clients, I should define the same 10 clients 100 times ? is there an alternative ?
3. One of our flows is backend micro-service that should be authenticated against an application (defined as  keycloak client), we would like to avoid keeping user/psw on the server for security reasons, is there a way that an admin can acquire a token and place it manually on the server file system for that micro service ? is there a option to generate this token in the keycloak UI ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

1. All Keycloak functionality is available via the [admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.3/rest-api/index.html), so you can automate this. The realm's public key is available via `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{realm}/`
2. A realm for each tenant will give a tenant-specific login page. Therefore this is the way to go - 10 clients registered 100 times. See more in the chapter [Client Registration](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_client_registration) of the Keycloak documentation. If you don't need specific themes, you can opt to put everything in one realm, but you will lose a lot of flexibility on that path.
3. If your backend micro service should appear like one (technical) user, you can issue an offline token that doesn't expire. [This is the online documentation for offline tokens](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_offline-access). Currently there is no admin functionality to retrieve an offline token for a user by an admin. You'll need to build this yourself. An admin can later revoke offline tokens using the given admin API.

Comment: The link for offline tokens is not longer valid and should now be https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_offline-access